# Looping through Html forms with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, loops, if-statement

Trying to validate a html form so that once all fields have been filled and a valid email address is entered, it creates a mock email with the details included inside the form. It works first time only at the moment and I would like it to always check that the First and last name fields are not empty.

Current Code:

```
function validate_form(thisform){
      with (thisform){
        if ((validate_required(firstname,lastname,email,"All fields must be filled out!")==false) || (validate_email(email,"Not a valid e-mail address!")==false)){
           firstname.focus();
           lastname.focus();
           email.focus();
           return false;
        }
           return true;         
        }
      }
```

Here is my Form

```
<form name="registration" action="mailto:example.example@example.com?subject='example'" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
Email : <input type="text" name ="email">
<input type= submit value="Send email" onclick="return validateForm();">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

**I have removed some syntax to read the form code**

Comment: When you say it works the first time only, what happens the second time? Any console errors?

Comment: Second time around it will submit if the email is typed formatted correctly, and will still submit if nothing is input into either first or last name fields. @Ozzy

Comment: Sounds like you're using global variables to check if the form has validated?

Comment: I'm using this function to validate if the fields are empty 'function validate_required(field,field2,field3,alerttxt){
  with (field,field2,field3){
   if (value==null|| value==""){
    alert(alerttxt);return false;
   }
   else{
    return true;
   }
 
  } 
 }'

Comment: That's not where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a34z195t/) and with just few changes it your validation works 
 - The main thing was to remove `return validateForm()` from `input type=submit`

http://jsfiddle.net/a34z195t/:

```
<script>
function validate_form(thisform) {
    with(thisform) {
        if ((validate_required(firstname, lastname, email, "All fields must be filled out!") == false) || (validate_email(email, "Not a valid e-mail address!") == false)) {
            firstname.focus();
            lastname.focus();
            email.focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

function validate_required(field, field2, field3, alerttxt) {
    with(field, field2, field3) {
        if (value == null || value == "") {
            alert(alerttxt);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
<form name="registration" action="mailto:example.example@example.com?subject='example'" onsubmit="return validate_form(this)" method="post">First Name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />
    <br />Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname" />
    <br />Email :
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send email" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```